# Arch Linux login command hangs

Tags: linux, arch-linux

After an system-wide update (pacman -Syyu), Arch hangs on every boot. When I try to boot into single user mode, it works, but as soon as I run `login`, the system hangs and there is no output. I have to restart at that point, since Control-C doesn't work.

I have already tried downgrading `util-linux` and `libutil-linux` to the versions they were before but that didn't fix it. I also reinstalled all packages, which also didn't fix it, and even tried `fsck` to no avail.

The output from `strace login` is as follows:

```
execve("/usr/bin/login", ["login"], 0x7ffcdaaea6a0 /* 11 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5628528c9000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffd5a0539f0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=176654, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 176654, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7efd5d5af000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libpam.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=55048, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efd5d5ad000
mmap(NULL, 2150416, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7efd5d39f000
mprotect(0x7efd5d3ac000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7efd5d5ab000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc000) = 0x7efd5d5ab000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libpam_misc.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=14040, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109520, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7efd5d19b000
mprotect(0x7efd5d19d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7efd5d39d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7efd5d39d000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000C\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
lseek(3, 792, SEEK_SET)                 = 792
read(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0e\355\2016\210\261\26\375\316\236\206j\322\376\362\347"..., 68) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2136840, ...}) = 0
lseek(3, 792, SEEK_SET)                 = 792
read(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0e\355\2016\210\261\26\375\316\236\206j\322\376\362\347"..., 68) = 68
lseek(3, 864, SEEK_SET)                 = 864
read(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32) = 32
mmap(NULL, 1848896, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7efd5cfd7000
mprotect(0x7efd5cff9000, 1671168, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7efd5cff9000, 1355776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7efd5cff9000
mmap(0x7efd5d144000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16d000) = 0x7efd5d144000
mmap(0x7efd5d191000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b9000) = 0x7efd5d191000
mmap(0x7efd5d197000, 13888, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efd5d197000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=14240, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 16528, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7efd5cfd2000
mmap(0x7efd5cfd3000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7efd5cfd3000
mmap(0x7efd5cfd4000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7efd5cfd4000
mmap(0x7efd5cfd5000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7efd5cfd5000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efd5cfd0000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7efd5cfd0b80) = 0
mprotect(0x7efd5d191000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7efd5cfd5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7efd5d5ab000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7efd5d39d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x5628520e9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7efd5d604000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7efd5d5af000, 176654)          = 0
getpid()                                = 970
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5628528c9000
brk(0x5628528ea000)                     = 0x5628528ea000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/login.defs", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5645, ...}) = 0
read(3, "#\n# /etc/login.defs - Configurat"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "gin\n#\nLOGIN_TIMEOUT\t\t60\n\n#\n# Whi"..., 4096) = 1549
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3031616, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3031616, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7efd5cceb000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2997, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2997
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_ZA.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_ZA.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_ZA/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x5628520e5230, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7efd5d00ee00}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, NULL, {sa_handler=0x5628520e5230, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7efd5d00ee00}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x5628520e5230, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7efd5d00ee00}, NULL, 8) = 0
alarm(60)                               = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[QUIT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7efd5d00ee00}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7efd5d00ee00}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 0)         = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=512*1024}) = 0
close(1023)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1022)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1021)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1020)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1019)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
...
close(17)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(16)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(15)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(14)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(13)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(12)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(11)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(10)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(9)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(8)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(7)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(6)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(5)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(4)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(3)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
setpgid(0, 0)                           = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x4, 0x1), ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/tty1", 4095) = 9
stat("/dev/tty1", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x4, 0x1), ...}) = 0
lstat("/dev/tty1", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x4, 0x1), ...}) = 0
access("/dev/tty1", R_OK|W_OK)          = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
fchown(0, 0, 0)                         = 0
fchmod(0, 0600)                         = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGTTOU {si_signo=SIGTTOU, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---
```

Comment: It shows some issue with locale. Did you set the locale properly during installation? Check `locale.gen` file.

Comment: Thank you! I had to add `LC_MESSAGES=en_ZA.UTF-8` to `/etc/locale.conf`. After a restart it works!

Comment: Okay, well it turns out that after another reboot I'm back to where I started. That line in `/etc/locale.conf` no longer works...